# Decompose form on $\Bbb R^4$ as the sum of squares of independent linear forms

Tags: quadratic-forms, sums-of-squares

I have the following task:

Decompose the following forms on $\mathbb{R}^4$ as the sum of squares of independent linear forms:

(1) $\phi(x) = x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_4 + x_4x_1$

(2) $\phi(x) = 9x_1^2-8x_2^2+5x_4^2+6x_1x_2+18x_1x_4+6x_2x_3-6x_2x_4+6x_3x_4$

Now for (1) I tried to write this as a matrix form, like this:

$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\\x_3\\x_4 \end{pmatrix}$.

Is it possible to get the sum of squares of independent linear forms in this way or am I totally wrong in this way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That depends. What is it that you’re planning to do with this matrix?

Comment: I thought that quadratic forms have a special matrix representation or something like that. For example a diagonal matrix. Thats why I tried to diagonalise it. But this matrix diagonalised returns complex eigenvalues.

Comment: They do, but with a _symmetric_ matrix, which yours is not. Use the symmetric part of the matrix that you’ve constructed instead (since only the symmetric part contributes to the quadratic form).

Comment: But is there a way to make this matrix symmetric?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in the last comment: take the symmetric part of that matrix. There’s a standard formula for that which you can look up if you don’t know it already.

Comment: Can you give me the name of this formula?

Comment: For the third time: **the symmetric part of a matrix**

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ Is this now the symmetric part of the matrix?

Comment: Close. You’re off by a factor of 2.

Comment: I need to divide it by 2, right? The formula would be $(A+A^T)/2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use *Gauß' method*:

1. Since you only have double products, factorise $\phi(x)$ first:
   $$\phi(x)=(x_1+x_3)(x_2+x_4)$$
   and use the polarisation identity:
   $$ab=\tfrac14\bigl((a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\bigr).$$
2. Collect first all terms containing $x_1$ and complete the square:
   \begin{align}
   \phi(x) &= 9x_1^2+6x_1x_2+18x_1x_4-8x_2^2+5x_4^2+6x_2x_3-6x_2x_4+6x_3x_4 \\
   &=\bigl(3x_1+x_2+3x_4)^2-(x_2+3x_4)^2-8x_2^2 +5x_4^2+6x_2x_3 -6x_2x_4 + 6x_3x_4\\
   &= \bigl(3x_1+x_2+3x_4)^2- 9x_2^2 -4x_4^2+6x_2x_3 -12x_2x_4 + 6x_3x_4
   \end{align}

and proceed in the same way for the form in three variables
$$\psi(x)=- 9x_2^2 -4x_4^2+6x_2x_3 -12x_2x_4 + 6x_3x_4.$$
As there is one variable less at each step, this ensures the forms are linearly independent.

Comment: Oops! *Lapsus calami*… Thank you for pointing it! 'Tis fixed now.

Comment: They *are* linearly independent.  If the coefficients of $x_1$ and $x_3$ are equal, those of $x_2$ and $x_4$ should be too.